# JAXB UnMarshaller memory consumption

Tags: groovy, gradle, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've created several classes from XSD by 'xjc' command and now I'm unMarshalling a large XML file by XMLStreamReader and JAXB (It reads it chunk by chunk) in Gradle/Groovy:

```
def getMemory(){
        long used  = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        return used / (1024*1024)
    }

def xmlUnMarshaller(FileReader fileReader) {
        System.out.println("Memory Before:${getMemory()}")

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory()
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(fileReader);
        def jContext = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(Patient.class)
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jContext.createUnmarshaller()
        def patientCount = 0
        while (xsr.hasNext()) {
            if (xsr.isStartElement() && xsr.getLocalName().equals("patient")) {
                def patient = (Subject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr)
                patientCount++
            } else {
                xsr.next()
            }
        }
        xsr.close()

        System.out.println("Memory After:${getMemory()}")
    }
```

In 'jaxb.properties' file, I have mentioned:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

***It works fine*** BUT uses plenty of memory! This is the memory status after running the jar file:

```
Memory Before:19.5550079345703125
Memory After :98.85445404052734375
```

I've used Gradle to build the jar file. Surprisingly if I debug the same code in Intellij, it shows different memory usage (which I guess it's reasonable):

```
Memory Before:45.2733917236328125
Memory After :37.20656585693359375
```

These are the dependencies that I've used on build.gralde:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.6.1'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.7-b41'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41'
    jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7'
}
```

Why does it happen? Why does it use so much memory when running the jar file?

Comment: Is it running out of memory?

Comment: If I continue unMarshalling other files (as I need to load and unMarshall more), it gradually uses more and more, and gets to a point where it uses 1.5G of memory! but does not throw any exception about 'out of memory'.

Comment: Sounds like it's working fine then

Comment: Thanks Tim, but why does it use so much memory? and it does not free the memory that it uses? if I continue loading more XML, I can see that the memory usage increases and it doesn't free up the memory. As far as I know if should return the memory, otherwise I guess there is a memory leakage somewhere.

Comment: Does it eventually run out of memory?

Comment: No, I tested it with several large XML files and it worked perfectly fine without any 'out of memory' exception.